# Should refresh tokens be signed?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, oauth

I'm not using an identity provider. I have a small system with access and refresh tokens and it works well.

Assume the system follows the "typical" approach:

- when user authenticates or refreshes: he gets a new refresh token
- refresh token is just an opque value, e.g. a random buffer
- a hash of it is stored in the database
- the client is a SPA

I've seen many references (tutorials, samples, etc.) which sign refresh tokens, e.g. HMAC-SHA256, and many don't.

But all the server needs to do is find the corresponding hash in the database. *So is there a benefit to signing the refresh token?*

Are these blogs/tutorials just blindly copying each other, or is there an actual security benefit?

Comment: Check the tutorials that sign the values if they also store the value or a hash of it on server side. I would assume that they sign the token so that they don't have to store it on the server. The token in such a case is also not fully random but contains some data part. So signing is a technology that allows you to externalize the token storage to the clients.

Comment: @Robert Smart deduction! I suppose that means such a scheme makes the refresh token stateless just like an access token. That does feel wrong though (personally, I store a hash of the refresh token).

Comment: @Robert As a corolary to your point, assuming you store a refresh token's hash, then am I right in assuming that signing it is pointless - it just adds a CPU-bound burden which has no security benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of approaches to tokens.  The first is simply an opaque identifier that refers to an entry in a database that the server has some permissions associated with.  The second is some sort of data which is digitally signed or verified using a MAC, which allows other parties (say, other services or possibly external parties) to verify the integrity of the token.

If you're using the first kind, there's no need to sign it.  You're not proving to anyone else that it's valid, and its validity is determined by what you have in the database, so signing it just wastes CPU.  The only thing you need to consider about the opaque identifier is that it is of sufficient size (at least 128 bits of entropy) and that it's generated using a CSPRNG to prevent guessing other values.  You may also wish to give it a special prefix or other special form to help tools that look for leaked tokens find them easily.  Other than that, a unique identifier is usually fine for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I would add to your answer, please tell me if I'm right: In the case where the refresh token is not signed and represents a database value, we must know it is valid for that user. Alone, it can be faked. So we have another token (access token, even if expired) which is signed and can be verified. That's why many APIs with a refresh endpoint only ask for the refresh token (in which case it's probably signed, or one also needs to provide a client secret, etc.), whereas many other APIs ask for access and refresh tokens (in which case the refresh token is probably not signed).

Comment: `You may also wish to give it a special prefix or other special form to help tools that look for leaked tokens find them easily` that's very clever, do such tools exist? You mean tools to search for leaked tokens on google, that sort of thing?

Comment: Some sites associate permissions with tokens such that a separate username or access token isn't necessary: it's bound to the token in the database already.  You can do that or not, as you see fit.  As for patterns, various organizations have secret scanning in place to detect (and possibly revoke) credentials committed accidentally to a repository.  GitHub, for instance, offers secret scanning as an add-on.